# Pull request not appearing in upstream repository

Tags: github, pull-request

A colleague of mine forked my GitHub repository, and he adds his modifications. However, when he makes a pull request, it is not reported to my repository: the list of open pull requests is still empty.

In order to apply his modifications on my work, I must go to his repository and apply the pull request myself

Unless I misunderstood the pull request concept, do you a have a solution on this? Should I recreate my repository?

I must inform you that repository was a private one before I made it public.

Comment: My apologizes for my late, I couldn't answer you earlier because of my job. My colleague told me that he exactly did what you said, but for strange reasons, when he want to make a pull request, the button disappears for confirmation. Maybe because he is not a collaborator... Thank you for you help by the way

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague should create a pull request that targets *your* repository. The easiest way to do this is to [navigate to your repository and create the pull request from there](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork):

> Confirm that the *base fork* is the repository you'd like to merge changes into. Use the *base branch* drop-down menu to select the branch of the upstream repository you'd like to merge changes into.

If the pull request is created properly, targeting your repository, you should see it in your list of pull requests.